# How to increase aws dynamodb index limit from 5

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Is it possible to increase the index from 5 to 15?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html

> Secondary Indexes Per Table You can define a maximum of 5 local
>   secondary indexes and 5 global secondary indexes per table.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html

> The Query operation finds items based on primary key values. You can
>   query any table or secondary index that has a composite primary key (a
>   partition key and a sort key).

If I understood this correct, you can set 1 main hashkey, 5 secondary keys and another 5 global... and you can only query against an index.

We are thinking about using DynamoDB for a NoSQL database but we are completely stumbed by this. In Mongo or Elastic or Solr.. you can query by pretty much any doc attr you want.

In this app we already have 15 attributes we know we will want to query against, but DynamoDB only offers the ability to index 5.. unless i am mistaken... is there another way to query aside from against a preset index?

Comment: After a few projects now with DynamoDB with a hand on my heart I truthful state i will try my absolute hardest to never use dynamodb ever again... utter waste of money. Just use mongodb and maintain the databases backups manually. DynamoDB as a service is about the only thing good about it, it is setup within seconds and we all blindly trust AWS won't go bang. Asside from that, speed is not that much faster than mongo, functionality is severely limited in comparison to mongo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> You can define a maximum of `5` local secondary indexes.
>
> There is an initial quota of `20` global secondary indexes per table. To request a service quota increase, see https://aws.amazon.com/support.

Source: [Secondary Indexes @ Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-secondary-indexes)

Unfortunately, 5 local secondary indexes(LSI) service quota could not be extended.

When you have more (>20) attributes to query from DynamoDB, it is not efficiently possible. You have to use Scan which evaluates all the items in the table, which is not efficient. You have to either move to a different database or use AWS ElasticSearch to index the attributes for searching.

Comment: Ah ok, so we can use scan to query for unindexed items? Also, i didn't know AWS has an elasticsearch as a service, i could only see elasticache

Comment: @John just remember what "scan" means in database terminology.  It is slow and costly in resource consumption because it reads through all rows.   It isn't what DynamoDB is designed to do, which is look up items by PK or a limited number of indexed attributes, at very large scale.

Comment: For posterity sake, I just want to point out that the 5 local secondary indexes and 20 global secondary indexes limits are no longer hard limits, but just default limits, and they can be increased by putting in a case with AWS support. I was curious if there is still a "hard limit", so as an experiment put in a support ticket asking for my limit to be increased to 50,000 indexes [and they approved it](https://i.imgur.com/IoqFJBt.png)

Answer (score 2):

The limit for number of global secondary index per table has been increased to **20**.
You can cut a support case incase you need to create more than **20 global secondary index** for a DynamoDB table.
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/12/amazon-dynamodb-increases-the-number-of-global-secondary-indexes-and-projected-index-attributes-you-can-create-per-table/

Comment: global secondary indeces are entire copies of the table that are kept in sync, so you perform a lot duplicate operations in updating items, but a local secondary index references the same table

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the answer was to wait. Now dynamodb supports 20 global secondary indexes. According to:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html

> There is an initial limit of 20 global secondary indexes per table. To
>   request a service limit increase see https://aws.amazon.com/support.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to circumvent the limit for number of indexes by overloading indexed column. For example, you may store multiple data attributes in the same partition key or sort key. The problem may arise when the values of those different attributes can overlap. In this case, you can, say, prepend a suffix that distinguishes between different attributes.

Let's take a look at an example. Let's say, we have a data set with attributes like `user-name`, `employee-name`, `company-name`, and you we want to store them all in a same indexed column (say partition key of a global secondary index). Some values for the attributes may overlap, so we "tag" our attributes with a prefix: `user#name`, `employee#name` and `company#name`.
This allows us to query with conditions like `begins_with(user#abc)` without mixing up different attributes but still having them all indexed.

More information is in the official AWS documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-gsi-overloading.html

Hope this helps.